# SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row con Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel-10

Buen dia.
Tengo una tabla llamada form_field_values, la cual guarda el valor de form_field la cual está relacionada con form, existe un form que pregunta por la condición del equipo este form se usa para devoluciones y garantías, el problema es que es que al ejecutar la siguiente función:

```
public function getSellers()
{
    $sellers = Service::query()
        ->join('orders', 'services.order_id', 'orders.id')
        ->join('products', 'services.id', 'products.service_id')
        ->join('form_submissions', 'products.id', 'form_submissions.product_id')
        ->join('statuses', 'form_submissions.status_id', 'statuses.id')
        ->join('types', 'services.type_id', 'types.id')
        ->join('types as parent_types', 'types.parent_id', 'parent_types.id')
        ->join('comments', 'services.id', 'comments.id')
        ->whereIn('statuses.str', ['form-status-warranty-process', 'form-status-return-process'])
        ->select(
            'orders.id as id_order',
            'orders.vtex_order_id as no_order',
            'products.sku as sku',
            'products.name as name_product',
            'products.imei as imei',
            'parent_types.name as classification',
            'orders.seller as sellerName',
            'comments.commentary',
            DB::raw(' (SELECT form_field_values.value
              FROM forms
              JOIN form_fields ON forms.id = form_fields.form_id
              JOIN form_field_values ON form_fields.id = form_field_values.form_field_id 
              JOIN form_submissions ON forms.id = form_submissions.form_id 
              JOIN products ON form_submissions.product_id = products.id
              JOIN services ON products.service_id = services.id
              WHERE form_fields.name = "Condicion del equipo" 
              AND forms.str in ("form-return-ingress","form-warranty-ingress")
              AND form_submissions.product_id = products.id
              ) as Condicion_del_equipo'),

           
        ->groupBy(
            'sellerName',
            'orders.id',
            'products.name',
            'products.sku',
            'products.imei',
            'parent_types.name',
            'orders.seller',
            'comments.commentary',
            'Condicion_del_equipo',
            'Operacion_salida',
            'Salida_procesamiento'
        )
        ->get();
    return $sellers;
}
```

me retorna el error SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row
lo cual es correcto ya que toda esa relación se guarda en una tabla pivote que se ve así
[image: Tabla pivote]

siendo el form_id 3 el que tiene la condición del equipo,requiero enviar la información de ambos registros, he intentado varias cosas pero no funcionan, espero alguien pueda ayudarme, estoy usando laravel 10 con la capa de repositorios.

Comment: Prueba con alguna función de agregación sobre `form_field_values.value` y analiza si te sirve así o es un error de datos en ambiente de desarrollo que no se presentará en un ambiente productivo o si es necesario agregar otro(s) criterio(s) para filtrar.

Comment: Si es un error de datos presente en desarollo, tarde o temprano se presentará en ambientes productivos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver el problema seguí el patrón repositorio de laravel (que ya estaba implementado en el proyecto) además de incluir en el where ID's para evitar que el resultado fuera mas de uno.
Muchas gracias!